# Deploy VUE project on Nginx, static file like css, js can not be found

Tags: vue.js, nginx

My OS is window, and deploy VUE project on Nginx server.

1. Build VUE project
   cd E:\test\test-project-frontend-demo
   npm install && npm run build
2. config nginx:

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1024;

pid                     logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    multi_accept        on;
    worker_connections  65535;
}

http {
    #MIME
    include             mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    #LOGGING
    log_format          main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                            '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                            '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log          logs/access.log     main;
    error_log           logs/error.log      warn;

    charset             utf-8;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    server_tokens       off;
    log_not_found       off;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 16M;
    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    gzip  on;

    #SITES
    include sites-available/project.conf;
}
```

project.conf

```
server {
    listen          80;
    listen          443 ssl;

    server_name project.testltd.com;

    # security
    include nginxconfig.io/security.conf;

    # logging
    access_log logs/project.access.log;
    error_log logs/project.error.log warn;

    # site project
    location / {
        alias E:/test/test-project-frontend-demo/dist;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # additional config
    include nginxconfig.io/general.conf;

    # ssl config
    include nginxconfig.io/self-signed.conf;
    include nginxconfig.io/ssl-params.conf;
}
```

start nginx:
    nginx.exe -c conf/nginx.conf

[image]

index.html can be access , and response is 200, but static file like css and js can not be accessed, Why?

Comment: Try changing `alias E:/test/test-project-frontend-demo/dist;` to `root E:/test/test-project-frontend-demo/dist;`

Comment: I have used `root` derective, failed.

Comment: Have you solved this? I found that Vue.js is serving directly from /public instead of hitting nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the index.html is using static path like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```

If so, it need to be relative path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
```

It can be set in your build tool config file.

For example, with Vite, in vite.config.js, set "base" option to empty string or "./".